# fullcalendar events are not displayed correctly

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I'm having an issue when displaying **fullcalendar** events, sometimes when the calendar is loaded for the first time the events are not entirely visible as shown in the image, and to fix it, I have to switch to the month view and return back to week view. Is there a way to fix this problem so the calendar is always loaded correctly ?

[image]

**EDIT:**

This is the html code of my calendar:

[image]

And this is the javascript code:

[image]

Comment: Do you get an error message? If so, please share it with us so we can help you better.

Comment: No, I don't get any error, and this problem does not occure every time the page is loaded, sometime the events are loaded correctly

Comment: Without any code or other information we can only guess what the issue might be. It looks like maybe some sort of CSS issue but there is no way of knowing without further info. See the [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) help page for guidance.

Comment: Thanks for your update. However, as per the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide, which you are encouraged to read before using the site, please don't post images of your code. Please edit your question to include the code as text and use the [formatting tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to present it nicely, so that it is usable for those who want to help you. Thanks

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557 also explains why images of code are unhelpful. I certainly cannot work on this question until you include your code in a usable way.

Comment: P.S. what this code you've posted _doesn't_ tell us is whether you've got a CSS issue - e.g. missing CSS files from fullCalendar, or maybe a conflict with other CSS on your page. To be honest, that is a far more likely cause for your problem.